# Build error while running

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I am trying to run a code snippet multiple numbers of times in C#.Project name is test.Initial number of times it's running properly but after that i am getting the following build error."Error 1 Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\test.exe" to "bin\Debug\test.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\test.exe' because it is being used by another process.test".
How can I get rid of this error.

Comment: go task manager and find the `test.exe` process currently running and kill them all. cleanup the project and rebuild

Comment: Damith, thanks for the reply but I tried everything but the issue is not getting resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because sometime `Test.exe` keeps running even after you finish executing test.

One solution is to kill `Test.exe` once your run is finished.
There could be some side effects because of this. You might see some Test run Errors in next runs

Better way is to disable Test Execution Running between runs

```
Go to    Tools > Options > Test Tools > Test Execution

  Unselect "Keep test execution engine running between test runs"
```

Can take this [Referance](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b85272d-5690-429e-a592-44a3fab26edc/unable-to-copy-file-objdebugxxxdll-to-bindebugxxxdll-the-process-cannot-access-the-file).

Comment: The solution which you gave is not working.Please help me out with some other alternative.

Comment: @Rajat ohh, i will see to this, wait

Answer (score 1):

That's because a protected version of you application is being run in memory by VS. You have to shut it down. You have many ways to solve this problem. The simplest one is:
in solution explorer, right click on you Test project, click Properties. in Test properties, go to Debug tab. Uncheck "Enable Visual Studio hosting process". You may need to restart VS.

By the way, if it's critical for you, upload you entire solution and I will take care of it.